# New column values based on combination of changing input columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset for different countries and sub national regions. The variable `country` determines the country (`a`, `b`, `c`), and the variable `region_country_X` has numeric values for the different subregions of that country (and is `NA` for cases in another country). See code below for the data frame:

```
set.seed(6543)
df <- data.frame(country = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
         region_country_a = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 1000, replace = TRUE),
         region_country_b = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), 1000, replace = TRUE),
         region_country_c = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3), 1000, replace = TRUE))
df$region_country_a <- ifelse(df$country != "a", NA, df$region_country_a)
df$region_country_b <- ifelse(df$country != "b", NA, df$region_country_b)
df$region_country_c <- ifelse(df$country != "c", NA, df$region_country_c)
```

The data frame's head looks like this:

```
> head(df, 5)
  country region_country_a region_country_b region_country_c
1       c                NA                NA                 1
2       b                NA                 3                NA
3       a                 2                NA                NA
4       c                NA                NA                 1
5       b                NA                 2                NA
```

I would now like to add a new variable with all regions in one column but can't figure out how to best go about this.

I would like `r` to do the following:

- add new column `regions`
- go through columns `country` and `region_country_a`, `..._b`, `..._c` and for each combination get a new value (counting from `0` for country `a`, region `0` upwards, adding the next highest number for each new country/ region combination).

And the resulting data frame would look something like this:

```
  country regions_country_a regions_country_b regions_country_c    regions
1       c                NA                NA                 1    18      #counting with a/0 = 0 etc., a7 = 7, b0 = 8 etc. 
2       b                NA                 3                NA    11       
3       a                 2                NA                NA    2        
4       c                NA                NA                 1    18       
5       b                NA                 2                NA    10
```

I'm not sure how I can address this best, since I'm rather new to `r`, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `dplyr::group_indices` if you just substract `1`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(id = group_indices(., country, region_country_a, region_country_b, region_country_c)-1) %>%
  head(5)

#   country region_country_a region_country_b region_country_c id
# 1       c                0                0                1 18
# 2       b                0                3                0 11
# 3       a                2                0                0  2
# 4       c                0                0                1 18
# 5       b                0                2                0 10
```

Comment: That's a much cleaner solution than mine!

Comment: Hey, that's a really elegant solution - thank a lot! However, I found that the column is not permanent; how can I permanently add this to the data frame (I need it later on)?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly. you are trying to encode each combination of the four columns with a number. If so, you get the unique combinations of those and then get an id from the row number and join it back to your original data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

df_un <- unique(df) %>%
  arrange(country) %>%
  mutate(region=row_number())

df <- left_join(df, df_un, by = c("country", "region_country_a", "region_country_b", "region_country_c"))
```